# Very simple Google-apps script results in syntax error

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, syntax-error, template-engine

I have a collection of Google App. scripts that I run as standalone apps., usually embedded into Google Sites. Yesterday I copied one of my functioning scripts and modified as I have done many times in the past but now the new scriptit does not run, it fails with a syntax error. Having stared at this extremely simple script for hours without a resolution I am thinking it may be a problem with Google, or some issue in my domain (Corp. domain).

```
function doGet() {
   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_ID');
   var lrN = ss.getSheetByName('NCMR').getLastRow();

t.statArray = ss.getSheetByName('NCMR').getRange('Z3:Z'+lrN+'').getValues();

return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

snip from the execution transcript when I try to run:

```
[17-04-13 06:39:26:322 PDT] Sheet.getRange([Z3:Z23]) [0.072 seconds]
[17-04-13 06:39:26:381 PDT] Range.getValues() [0.058 seconds]
[17-04-13 06:39:26:382 PDT] Function.apply([[]]) [0 seconds]
[17-04-13 06:39:26:389 PDT] Execution failed: SyntaxError: Syntax error. (line 8, file "Code") [0.254 seconds total runtime]
```

Error from debugger:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

and then it has the following in the left hand pane of the debugger:

```
<Unknown file>null [0]
Code : doGet [8]
```

Any help or insight will be much appreciated. Apologies if this is a lay up and/or has already been answered.

EDIT to add html file:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table>
<tr><td><b> Id</b></td></tr>
<?= for (var i = 0; i < statArray.length; i++) { ?>
  <?= for (var j = 0; j < statArray[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <tr><td><?= statArray[i] ?></td>
  <?= } ?>
    </tr>
<?= } ?>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error in HTML file when you try to evaluate it throws an error in line 8 or t.evaluate step. Could you share your HTML file?

Comment: @Jack Brown: Yep, you are a genius! It was right there starring me in the face the entire time, the printing scriplet in the HTML file was supposed to be standard notation (<? . . . ?>), lesson learned on willy-nilly copy and paste. However, I still need the printing scriplet for the actual array vars. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

**For reference: The author of the question figured out the problem/syntax error**

The reason for the error was a syntax error in a scriptlet used in the html i.e modify this:

```
<?= for (var i = 0; i < statArray.length; i++) { ?>
```

to a standard scriptlet tag

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < statArray.length; i++) { ?>
```

Html code should be the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table>
<tr><td><b> Id</b></td></tr>
<? for (var i = 0; i < statArray.length; i++) { ?>
  <? for (var j = 0; j < statArray[i].length; j++) { ?>
    <tr><td><?= statArray[i] ?></td>
  <? } ?>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use index.html

```js
function doGet() {
   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_ID');
   var lrN = ss.getSheetByName('NCMR').getLastRow();

t.statArray = ss.getSheetByName('NCMR').getRange('Z3:Z'+lrN+'').getValues();

return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I just tried adding the .html extension but it still fails :(

Comment: hum... can you supply your index.html file as well?

Comment: When I run your code with a blank index.html template I receive 0 errors. you might look into that.

Comment: Yep, it was the html file, thanks for your help and quick response.